# Could not get values from request.getParameter Java JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, post, request

Below is my code where i would be using to pass data to another domain. I am having this problem where with request.getParameter("accType"); the value could not be retrieved. However , other value is working fine, the names are correct and form has a post method on it, can anybody help me with this? Thanks in advance.

```
<%-- 
    Document   : viewEmployee
    Created on : Jan 23, 2018, 12:06:44 AM
    Author     : AaronLee
--%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@ page import = "da.employeeDA" %>
<jsp:useBean id="employeeDA" class="da.employeeDA" scope="application" ></jsp:useBean>
<jsp:setProperty name="employeeDA" property="*" />
<%--import domain page--%>
<%@ page import = "domain.employee" %>
<jsp:useBean id="employee" class="domain.employee" scope="application" ></jsp:useBean>
<jsp:setProperty name="employee" property="*" />
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%!
    ResultSet rs = null;
%>
<html>
    <head>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <%--import css--%>


        <link href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="css/website.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <%--Bootstrap CSS--%>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>


        <title>Account Details</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="homepage.jsp">Document</a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                        <li><a href="addInvoice.jsp">+ Document</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="addClaim.jsp">+ Claim</a></li>
                        <li><a href="projectDisplayData.jsp">Search Document</a></li>
                        <li><a href="displayClaim.jsp">Search Claim</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Account<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="LogOut.jsp">Log Out</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="content">
                <%
                    //login session
                    String username = null;
                    if (session.getAttribute("username") == null) {
                        response.sendRedirect("Login.jsp");
                        username = null;
                        return;
                    } else {
                        username = session.getAttribute("username").toString();

                    }

                %>
                <%                    try {
                   rs =     employeeDA.searchEmployee(username);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.getMessage();
                    }

                    if (rs.next()) {
                %>
                <form method="POST" action="viewEmployee.jsp" >
                    Account Type :<br/>
                    <input type="text" value="<%=rs.getString("ACCTYPE")%>"  name="accType" disabled /><br/><br/>
                    Employee ID :<br/>
                    <input type="text" value="<%=rs.getString("EMPLOYEEID")%>" name="employeeID" disabled/><br/><br/>
                    Name : <br/>
                    <input type="text" value="<%=rs.getString("EMPLOYEENAME")%>" name="employeeName"/><br/><br/>
                    Contact Number :<br/>
                    <input type="text" value="<%=rs.getString("EMPLOYEECONTACTNO")%>" name="employeeContactNo"/><br/><br/>
                    <div class="panel-group" id="panelGrp">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Password</a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                <div class="panel-body">Current Password :<br/>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control"/><br/>
                                    New Password : <br/>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password"/><br/>

                                    Confirm Password : <br/>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" /><br/>

                                    <input type="submit" value="Change Password" name="selection" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg  btn-square" id="changepw"/>

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Update" id="changepw" name="selection" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg  btn-square"/>

                </form>
                <%}%>
            </div>
            <div class="footer"></div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>


<%if (request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {

    if("Update".equals(request.getParameter("selection"))){



try{
   employeeDA.updateEmployee(employee);

}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.getMessage();
}

}else if("Change Password".equals(request.getParameter("selection"))){
    try{
    employeeDA.changePassword(username,request.getParameter("password"));


}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.getMessage();
}

}
}
out.println(request.getParameter("accType"));
out.println(employee.getAccType());
%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`disabled`  elements in a form will not be submitted. You may have to use `readonly`.